# Modifying the text of RadCheckedDropDownList

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, telerik

I am dynamically adding and populating a RadCheckedDropDownList inside a panel in my Winform application.

The current functionality of the RadCheckedDropDownList is if I select more than one value from the list, the values will be listed in the combo box separated by a separator. Like in the image below

[image: RadCheckedDropDownList with 2 selected values]

My question is how can I change the displayed value to "Multiple", instead of displaying values separated by separator when multiple values are selected.Preferably the multiple should be read only without the token.

Comment: What do you mean with "change the displayed value to Multiple"?

Comment: If user selects 3 values for example monday, tuesday, thursday. Instead of showing "Monday;Tuesday;Thursday",  it must display "Multiple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you can add a new element in the editable part of the control, which will be responsible for displaying your text without messing up with the control functionality.

Then you can use the ItemCheckedChanged event which will get triggered when an item is checked, and here you can see how many items are currently checked, and if more than one, show the element with the text and hide the tokens.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)

    AddCheckedDropDownList()
    AddHandler radCheckedDropDownList1.ItemCheckedChanged, AddressOf radCheckedDropDownList1_ItemCheckedChanged

    radCheckedDropDownList1.CheckedDropDownListElement.AutoCompleteEditableAreaElement.Children.Add(New LightVisualElement() With { _
        Key .Text = "Multiple" _
    })
    AdjustControlText()
End Sub

Private Sub radCheckedDropDownList1_ItemCheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As RadCheckedListDataItemEventArgs)
    AdjustControlText()
End Sub

Private Sub AdjustControlText()
    If radCheckedDropDownList1.CheckedItems.Count > 1 Then
        radCheckedDropDownList1.CheckedDropDownListElement.AutoCompleteEditableAreaElement.AutoCompleteTextBox.ViewElement.Visibility = Telerik.WinControls.ElementVisibility.Collapsed
        DirectCast(radCheckedDropDownList1.CheckedDropDownListElement.AutoCompleteEditableAreaElement.Children(1), LightVisualElement).DrawText = True
    Else
        radCheckedDropDownList1.CheckedDropDownListElement.AutoCompleteEditableAreaElement.AutoCompleteTextBox.ViewElement.Visibility = Telerik.WinControls.ElementVisibility.Visible
        DirectCast(radCheckedDropDownList1.CheckedDropDownListElement.AutoCompleteEditableAreaElement.Children(1), LightVisualElement).DrawText = False
    End If
End Sub
```